# Facing issue with sending message from cloud to device iot hub via rabbitmq(amqp protocol)

Tags: php, azure, rabbitmq, azure-storage, azure-iot-hub

I want to send message from cloud to device iot hub with amqp protocol for this i am using rabbitmq message broker with the [reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) in php. I have tried the below code on localhost:

```
//send.php
    <?php
        require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
    use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('HUBNAME.azure-devices.net', 5671
    , 'HUBNAME.azure-devices.net/DEVICENAME/?api-version=2018-06-30'
    , 'SharedAccessSignature sr=HUBNAME.azure-devices.net
    &sig=XXXX&se=XXXX&skn=iothubowner');

    $channel = $connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);
    $json = '{"id":123, "value":"xyz"}';
    $msg = new AMQPMessage($json);
    $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');    
    echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";    
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
```

when i run this `send.php` file i am getting error:

> fatal error: Uncaught
>   PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or
>   closed connection in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amqp\vendor\php-amqplib\php-amqplib\PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO.php:222

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send Cloud-to-Device messages from your IotHub using rabbitmq.

"
You send cloud-to-device messages through a service-facing endpoint **(/messages/devicebound)**. A device then receives the messages through a device-specific endpoint **(/devices/{deviceId}/messages/devicebound)**.

To target each cloud-to-device message at a single device, IoT Hub sets the **to** property to **/devices/{deviceId}/messages/devicebound**.
"

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d).

You can\should leverage the Azure IoT Hub Service SDKs - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-hub-service-sdks).

Comment: Thanks, But this endpoint look like work with https protocol and i read that for iot messaging avoid protocol https use amqp or mqtt, About the sdk i can only use php sdk which is not available there, Do you have any idea how can i deal with amqp to send message to iot hub from my server ?

Comment: I am confused, please clarify if you want to send messages from your device to IoTHub (D2C) or send messages from IoTHub to your device (C2D)? Thanks

Comment: I had to deal with multiple devices from the IoT hub with my backend that was PHP and for this was looking for the API which orders to the IoT hub to send the message over multiple devices. by the above way I was able to deal with a single device, So i got the new option schedule job and which works for me, have I chosen the right option?

Comment: Hi @BunkerBoy indeed jobs is a supported scenario on Azure IoTHub - Jobs execute device twin updates and direct methods against a set of devices at a scheduled time.